# Interpreting cProfile results: total vs. cumulative time in small function

Tags: python, optimization, profiling, cprofile

Most of my Python program is spent in a method called `_build_userdbs`. I'm using the awesome tool [SnakeViz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) which helps interpreting the results. There's a screenshot below.

[image: Visualization from SnakeViz]

So right now, in that picture, I'm in `_build_userdbs`. The big green circle right outside of that is a method called `_append_record` and, as you can see, it takes up almost all of `_build_userdbs`. I understand this.

But here's the confusing part. The green circle outside of the inner green circle (which takes up the *vast majority* of the time) is the cumulative time of the `_append_record` *minus* the cumulative time of the functions called in `_append_record`.

Quantitatively, `_append_record`'s cumulative time is **55970 seconds**. That's the inner green circle. Its total time is 54210 seconds. That's the outer green circle.

`_append_record`, as you can see if you open that image in a new tab, calls a couple other functions. Those are:

- `json.dumps()` (459 seconds cumulative)
- `_userdb_scratch_file_path()` (161 seconds cumulative)
- `open` (2160 seconds cumulative)
- `print` (less than .1% of frame so not displayed)

Alright, this makes sense; because of the relatively small difference between `_append_record`'s cumulative time and total time, it must be doing a lot of processing in its own stack frame, rather than delegating it to other functions. But here's the body of the function:

```
def _append_record(self, user, record):
    record = json.dumps(record)
    dest_path = self._userdb_scratch_file_path(user)
    with open(dest_path, 'at') as dest:
        print(record, file=dest)
```

So where is all of this processing going on? Is this function call overhead that accounts for the difference? Profiling overhead? Are these results just inaccurate? Why isn't the `close()` function called?